# Windows Installer does not COM register assembly

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, .net-assembly

My problem is described here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Installation/Q_28093898.html by another guy. I just copied the text.

*I've created a .net assembly in VisualStudio 2010 and I've included a Setup And 
Deployment project that installs the assembly into GAC.
But, I would like to make it COM callable and therefore I've selected vsdrpCOM for 
the assembly in the installer project.
Though, the assembly does not get COM registered when I run the installer.
If i register it manually it works, so it's nothing wrong with the assembly.
Does someone have a clue about whats wrong?*

**UPDATE:**

Now I've got more facts about this problem. In my project I choose **vsdrpCom** in Register property and Global Assembly Cache in Folder property. After doing this my ActiveX is not working.
**But** when I choose **vsdrpDoNotRegister** in Register property and Global Assembly Cache in Folder property, and after installation I use RegAsm to register my ActiveX control. Then everything is working fine.

Comment: This is a non-specific "it doesn't work" question.  You will have to explain how you *know* it doesn't work.  Describe the exact exception you get, show a stack trace, observe the installer writing the keys to the registry with SysInternals' ProcMon and show what's different from the keys on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your Setup and Deployment Project if you click on DLL file in the properties window you should set for "Register" property to something like "xxxxCOMxxxx". Not sure what is the exact option.

Edit:

```
vsdrfCOM 
vsdrfCOMSelfReg 
vsdrfCOMRelativePath
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I installed it for current user. Installation for all users have helped to solve the problem.